# Different results when I call API from c#

Tags: c#, api

I have a code to build an API in one application in c#

```
    [Route("api/SearchSelect")]
    public string Get(string paramOne = null, string paramTwo = null, string P3 = null, string P4=null)
    {
        return "The [Route] with multiple params worked.\nP1 : " + paramOne + "    P2 : " + paramTwo;
    }
```

and code to get the API results in c#

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44319/api/SearchSelect?&Parm1=&Parm2=&Parm3=&Parm4=Test");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;  
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.ToString(), (typeof(DataTable)));
```

When I get the values of response in the 2nd code

I get this

```
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcX19EZWVwTWVkXFNvZnR3YXJlXEFQSXNcQ0RBUElzXENEQVBJc1xhcGlcU2VhcmNoU2VsZWN0?=
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 14 May 2021 06:19:08 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 58
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
    Content: {System.Net.Http.StreamContent}
    Headers: {Pragma: no-cache
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcX19EZWVwTWVkXFNvZnR3YXJlXEFQSXNcQ0RBUElzXENEQVBJc1xhcGlcU2VhcmNoU2VsZWN0?=
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Fri, 14 May 2021 06:19:08 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
}
    IsSuccessStatusCode: true
    ReasonPhrase: "OK"
    RequestMessage: {Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://localhost:44319/api/SearchSelect?&Parm1=&Parm2=&Parm3=&Parm4=weff', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
}}
    StatusCode: OK
    Version: {1.1}
```

Which does not have any value form the API

but when I call the URL directly in the browser

I get this result which is correct

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-custom-link"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-general-link"/>
<style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
<style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-native-style"/>
The [Route] with multiple params worked. P1 : P2 :
</string>
```

Comment: The correct results is xml while you are getting jsone.  Either a HTTP header is different of a parameter in the URL is different.  Also the Source Files are Base64 which leads me to believe the message is GZIP.  So may be the http header is missing for GZIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're performing a .ToString() on the entire response object instead of the response's Content property. From the Microsoft docs (Content property at bottom of screenshot):

[image]

Perform the .ToString() on response.Content and you should be good.

Comment: response itself does not have any results..
i suppose to get this value "The [Route] with multiple params worked. P1 : P2 :" somewhere in the response but I didn't get any

Answer (score 0):

> `ToString` method, which is by default inherited by every object
> created will be returning the fully qualified name of the type which
> the object is of, if it is not overridden with custom logic.

This is why you are getting `System.Net.Http.StreamContent` as the content of this request. The proper way to get the result returned by an http client is as follows(*with your code*)

`DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);`

**Note: it is strongly recommended not to use `Result` over an awaitable object. You got to use async-await pattern properly**